# Select Nth value in access database (SQL)

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010, nth-element

I'm trying to select specific values in an Access database.
So the database contains many colums, I'm only able to select the first values, or last:

```
SELECT Column1, First(Column7) AS Column7_1, First(Column8) AS FirstOfColumn8, [Column1] & [Column7_1] AS [Column1&Column7]
FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY Column1;
```

Now what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the nth values in those columns. What would be perfect is if SQL would recognize third(Column7)...
I tried the following:

```
SELECT Column1, First(Column7) AS Column7_1, First(Column8) AS FirstOfColumn8, [Column1] & [Column7_1] AS [Column1&Column7]
FROM [Table1]
WHERE Column7 > (SELECT First(Column7) FROM [Table1]) AND Column8 > SELECT First(Column8) FROM [Table1]) 
GROUP BY Column1;
```

But this is not getting me there. the values from the different columns do not correspond anymore.
Any guess on how I could get this?
Thanks

Comment: you have no `order by` on any of your showed querys. if `order by` is missing first(), third() or nth() will result in a meaningless value, that is because sql querys (also in access) do not guaranty order if it is not specified. side note: third() and nth() do not exists

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, selecting a column by column number with the aforementioned syntax is not really supported with SQL.

Something similar to the following could do the trick (with dynamic SQL):

```
get list of column names in given table*
for each column name
  do this
end
```

*The below query could be of use!

```
SELECT s.NAME SchemaName, 
       t.NAME TableName, 
       c.NAME ColumnName 
FROM   sys.columns c 
       INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
               ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
               ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies, 
what I forgot to specify is that I'm actually not trying the nth cell in a column; it's more about getting the nth value contained in a specific colmn.
For example, take the following table

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
A1       Prop1     20
A1       Prop1     20
A2       Prop2     15
A2       Prop1     20
A3       Prop2     15
A3       Prop3     5 
A3       Prop3     5 
A4       Prop1     20
A4       Prop2     15
A4       Prop3     5
A4       Prop4     10
```

I would therefore like to select the nth values from column 2 for each column1id, so that to get for
first element:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
A1       Prop1     20
A2       Prop1     20
A3       Prop2     15
A4       Prop1     20
```

for second element:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3

    A2       Prop2     15
    A3       Prop3     5 
    A4       Prop2     15
```

and for the fourth:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3

    A4       Prop4     10
```

hope it makes sense